# Is there any way in flutter for converting String to a new Function?

Tags: flutter

I have a text field and this text field gives me a String and I want to convert this String to a Function. for example >>>

```
"{
  print("a")
}"
```

this is the String and I want this String to be a function like this>>>

```
{
  print("a")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way in my mind.

1. using textField with text controller to get data after user type
2. to use that string to make sure that string which user typed will meet two different regex patterns which shown on the pictures.
3. and then using if..else to invoke print().

```dart
RegExp regExp1 = new RegExp("your algorium"); <- to find print
RegExp regExp2 = new RegExp("your algorium"); <- to find "xxxx"
var a = regExp1.hasMatch("{print("a")}")
var b = regExp2.hasMatch("{print("a")}")
if ( a && b)
{
  String test = regExp2.stringMatch("{print("a")}").toString()
  print(test);
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: you are right, but if we want to create a system like this for all of dart functions this will take a lot of time. Thanks